# OMV: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed

Tags: nfs

1. I've flashed an OMV (openmediavault) image on an SD-card and fired up my R-Pi.
2. I've created a share and would like to export it via NFS.
3. When enabling the NFS-server it fails.
4. I did some digging in the logs and found references to a dependency-problem and the following error message:

> -- Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has begun starting up.
>       Dec 05 22:49:17 datavault-pi systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited,     code=exited status=32
>       Dec 05 22:49:17 datavault-pi systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration 
>    filesystem.
>        -- Subject: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed

**Q** What do I need to do to get the `proc-fs-nfsd.mount`-service started?

Comment: What log are you digging to find the message? Can you please execute the command `systemctl status proc-fs-nfsd.mount`? Please paste the output into your question.

Comment: @Ingo Please see my answer. Got the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful when installing OMV on R-Pi! (See ref. [here](https://github.com/openmediavault/openmediavault/issues/278#issuecomment-459685098).)

1. Download [image](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/) from github.
2. `unxz` the image. (With etcher you don't need to uncompress the image.)
3. `dd` image to sd-card.
4. Boot raspberry and be patient and let the system update all it's components to the current version. There is almost no or any output, so it's best to boot and leave the R-Pi alone for the recommended 20 min.
5. Best of luck! I got it working and so you can too ;-)